# Tengo un problema de herencia multiple en python

Tags: python, poo, herencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Solo he podido realizar una clase llamada madre, El problema me pide que realice 5 clases(Madre, padre, hijo, tio, tia), todas las clases recibiran el atributo nombre y edad.
La clase hijo heredara de la clase padre y madre y recibira como atributo el nombre de su padre y madre.
Todas las clases tendran el metodo presentarse() y uno extra(EN la clase madre que realice ya no se me ocurre que mas poner) y el metodo presentarse debera incluir nombre y edad del objeto.
finalmente se crea una ultima clase llamada familia y se deberá instanciar un objeto de cada clase.

```py
class Madre():
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad= edad

    def presentarse(self):
        print("Mi nombre es",self.nombre, "y tengo", self.edad,"años de edad")
         
mimadre = Madre("Bulma", "34")
mimadre.presentarse()

class Padre(Madre):
    pass
mipadre = Padre ("vegeta","37")
mipadre.presentarse()
```

Comment: te falta llenar la clase `Padre`, de lo contrario no tiene sentido crearla

Comment: Padre no deriva de Madre. Padre no es una especialización de Madre.

Comment: El ejercicio tal como te lo han planteado es un desastre conceptual. La herencia en POO no se usa para modelar relaciones de parentesco, sino relaciones de "es un tipo de". Así por ejemplo una clase Bicicleta podría heredar de una clase Vehiculo, porque una bicicleta "es un tipo de" vehículo. La herencia múltiple es más compleja aún pues sería para modelar cuándo algo es "un tipo de" otras dos cosas. Por ejemplo un coche autónomo podría "ser un tipo de" Vehiculo, pero también de Robot. En tu caso, un hijo no es "un tipo de padre pero también de madre". No tiene sentido lo que te están pidiendo

Comment: Y mucho menos aún hacer que una Familia herede de todas las otras clases. Una Familia no "es un tipo de Padre, Madre, Hijo, Tio, Tia". Más bien una Familia _"está compuesta de"_ todo eso, por lo que el patrón correcto sería aplicar composición en lugar de herencia. Buscate otro curso de programación orientada a objetos.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas 

Answer (score 3):

El planteamiento de la pregunta es una atrocidad, una cosa absurda.

El planteamiento correcto parte por definir la clase `Persona`. Una persona tiene nombre, fecha de nacimiento y sexo.

Las personas tienen relaciones entre si. Una persona puede relacionarse con múltiples otras: puede ser hijo, hermano y padre.

Finalmente, una familia es un conjunto de personas.

**Clase Persona**

Definimos constantes simbólicas de clase para identificar las relaciones entre personas (HIJO, PADRE, ...)

```
class Persona:
    HIJO = "hijo"
    PADRE = "papá"
    MADRE = "mamá"
    ESPOSOS = "esposo"

    def __init__(self, nombre, nacimiento, sexo):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.nacimiento = nacimiento
        self.sexo = sexo
        self.relaciones = []

    def agregar_relacion(self, persona, tipo):
        self.relaciones.append((persona, tipo))

    def __str__(self):
        rel = ",".join([f"{x[0].nombre} {x[1]}" for x in self.relaciones])
        return f"{self.nombre}, {self.nacimiento}, {self.sexo}. Relaciones: {rel}"
```

Cada objeto `Persona` tiene una lista de relaciones inicialmente vacía.

Lo esencial es que no existe una clase para representar el rol de Madre, Padre o Hijo. Este rol se representa a través de una entrada en la lista de relaciones.

La lista de relaciones contiene tuplas `(persona, codigo_relacion)`.

**Clase Familia**

```
class Familia:
    def __init__(self):
        self.personas = []

    def agregar_persona(self, persona):
        self.personas.append(persona)

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([f"{x}" for x in self.personas])
```

La clase simplemente contiene la lista de personas que la conforman.

#### Demo

Creemos tres personas:

```
papa = Persona("Juan", "1990", "M")
mama = Persona("Maria", "1991", "S")
hijo = Persona("Jorge", "2010", "M")
```

y establezcamos las relaciones entre ellos:

```
papa.agregar_relacion(hijo, Persona.PADRE)
mama.agregar_relacion(hijo, Persona.MADRE)
papa.agregar_relacion(mama, Persona.ESPOSOS)
mama.agregar_relacion(papa, Persona.ESPOSOS)
hijo.agregar_relacion(papa, Persona.HIJO)
hijo.agregar_relacion(mama, Persona.HIJO)
```

luego agrupemos la familia:

```
familia = Familia()
familia.agregar_persona(papa)
familia.agregar_persona(mama)
familia.agregar_persona(hijo)
```

y veamos que resulta de todo esto:

```
print("Papa: ", papa)
print("Mama:", mama)
print("Hijo:", hijo)
print("Familia:")
print(familia)
```

produce:

```
Papa:  Juan, 1990, M. Relaciones: Jorge papá,Maria esposo
Mama: Maria, 1991, S. Relaciones: Jorge mamá,Juan esposo
Hijo: Jorge, 2010, M. Relaciones: Juan hijo,Maria hijo
Familia:
Juan, 1990, M. Relaciones: Jorge papá,Maria esposo
Maria, 1991, S. Relaciones: Jorge mamá,Juan esposo
Jorge, 2010, M. Relaciones: Juan hijo,Maria hijo

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Notas

Este modelamiento soporta familias de separados con hijos previos, matrimonios del mismo sexo, solteros que adoptan, etc.

Puedes hacer búsquedas a partir de un individuo. Si quieres saber quienes son sus abuelos, es cosa de buscar hacia atrás a través de su lista de relaciones.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta gracias 